# Flutter: How can i solve this errors in every state

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, riverpod

I have a serious problem in Flutter with Riverpod. I am just starting to learn it, but I am encountering errors with every `.state`, and no AI has been able to help me solve the problem.

Here is the complete code:

```
// my_button_widget.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final buttonSelectedProvider = StateProvider<bool>((ref) => false);

class MyButtonWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Riverpod Button Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
              (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed))
                  return Colors.orange;
                return ref.watch(buttonSelectedProvider).state //error in .state
                    ? Colors.orange
                    : Colors.white; // Use the component's default.
              },
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            ref.read(buttonSelectedProvider).state = //error in .state
                !ref.read(buttonSelectedProvider).state; //error in .state
          },
          child: Text('Press me'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The suggestion from VS Code is as follows:

> The getter 'state' isn't defined for the type 'bool'. Try importing
> the library that defines 'state', correcting the name to the name of
> an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
> 'state'.dartundefined_getter Type: InvalidType

My version of Riverpod in `pubspec.yaml` is: `flutter_riverpod: ^2.4.9`."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod/changelog#210):

> Deprecated StateProvider.state Instead, use either ref.watch(stateProvider) or ref.read(stateProvider.notifier).state =

And avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).